# PHP - compare and filter two arrays with different dimensions

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I am trying to filter two arrays to get a final result with user ids from my mysql database

I have two arrays the first one:

```
print_r($arr_partner_id);
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 335 [id_partner] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 469 [id_partner] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 457 [id_partner] => 1 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 339 [id_partner] => 0 ) 
[4] => Array ( [id] => 361 [id_partner] => 0 ) )
```

and the second one:

```
print_r($arr_member_id);
Array ( 
[0] => 457 
[1] => 469 
[2] => 339 
[3] => 361 )
```

now i want compare these two only with their ids and delete the ids that are not included in the "$arr_member_id" Array. This my "reference Array" that means i only need the ids (457,469,339,361)

for the final result it should be looking like this:

```
print_r($arr_partner_final_id);
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 469 [id_partner] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 457 [id_partner] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 339 [id_partner] => 0 ) 
[3] => Array ( [id] => 361 [id_partner] => 0 ) )
```

i tryed it with foreach

```
foreach ($arr_partner_id as $key => $usr_ids) {
    if($arr_partner_id[$key]['id'] ==  $arr_member_id[$key]) {
        // do something
    }   
}
```

but the "keys" are different this should not working...

Comment: In your `foreach` you specify the key as `$key1`, but in the `if` statement you use `$key`, is this a typo in the question, or is your code like this?

Comment: sry a typing error from me...i correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Working example : http://codepad.org/ApFcA3Zo)

```
<?php

$arr_partner_id=array ( 
'0' => array ( 'id' => 335, 'id_partner' => 0 ) ,
'1' => array ( 'id' => 469, 'id_partner' => 1 ) ,
'2' => array ( 'id' => 457, 'id_partner' => 1 ) ,
'3' => array ( 'id' => 339, 'id_partner' => 0 ) ,
'4' => array ( 'id' => 361, 'id_partner' => 0 ) ) ;


$arr_member_id=array ( 
'0' => 457 ,
'1' => 469 ,
'2' => 339 ,
'3' => 361 ) ;

$final =array();

foreach($arr_partner_id as $arr)
{
  foreach($arr_member_id as $parr)
  {
     if($arr['id'] == $parr)
    {
    $final[]=$arr;
    }
   } 
}


print_r($final);

?>
```

Comment: There should be a break inside the inner foreach to exit the loop when the condition is met, so you don't waste computer cycles unnecessarily.

Comment: @Borgtex Thanks for your comment. Will keep that in mind in future.

Answer (score 3):

making it as simple, and using just one loop to loop through the array and checkin if the id is present in another set of array using `in_array()`

try this

```
for($i=0;$i<count($arr_partner_id);$i++){
  if(!in_array($arr_partner_id[$i]['id'],$arr_member_id)){
     unset($arr_partner_id[$i]);
  }
}

print_r($arr_partner_id);
```

try it [here](http://codepad.org/5ivoFzPm)

AND yes!! if you want seperate arrays for that then simply modify the code..create new array and push the elements that is present in array

```
$finalArray=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($arr_partner_id);$i++){
  if(in_array($arr_partner_id[$i]['id'],$arr_member_id)){
    $finalArray[]=$arr_partner_id[$i];
 }
}

print_r($finalArray);
```

Comment: with that solution the index begins with "1" not with "0" because in this case the first row was affected...but if for example the third row is affected the index is (0,1,3,4) i am not sure but this can bring problems...

Comment: hmm.. the first solution has that problem.. since it deletes the index..and should use it only when you have nothing to do with array index..  anyways i provided the second solution.. with which it shouldn't matter... creating new array and pushing the elements that is present in the array.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
foreach ($arr_member_id as $usr_id){
   foreach ($arr_partner_id as $partner){
     if ($usr_id == $partner['id']) {$arr_partner_final_id[]=$partner;break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution (without explicit looping):

```
$arr_partner_id=array ( 
'0' => array( 'id' => 335, 'id_partner' => 0 ),
'1' => array( 'id' => 469, 'id_partner' => 1 ),
'2' => array( 'id' => 457, 'id_partner' => 1 ),
'3' => array( 'id' => 339, 'id_partner' => 0 ),
'4' => array( 'id' => 361, 'id_partner' => 0 ));


$arr_member_id=array ( 
'0' => 457,
'1' => 469,
'2' => 339,
'3' => 361);


function compare($v){global $arr_member_id;return in_array($v['id'], $arr_member_id);}
var_dump($arr_partner_id = array_filter($arr_partner_id, 'compare'));
```

Answer (score 0):

better you use mysql itself do this task. but if you need to continue with this use [in array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function to check the second array as given below,

```
foreach ($arr_partner_id as $key => $usr_ids) {
  if(in_array($usr_ids["id"], $arr_member_id)) {
    // do something
  }   
}
```