# How to compare and filter 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays, web, filter, compare

first array like this

```
$zones_array1 = array();
      $zones_array1[] = array('id' => 'Alabama', 'text' => 'Alabama');
      $zones_array1[] = array('id' => 'Alaska', 'text' => 'Alaska');
      $zones_array1[] = array('id' => 'Arizona', 'text' => 'Arizona');
      $zones_array1[] = array('id' => 'Arkansas', 'text' => 'Arkansas');
```

second array like this

```
$zones_array2 = array();
      $zones_array2[] = array('id' => 'Alaska', 'text' => 'Alaska');
      $zones_array2[] = array('id' => 'Arizona', 'text' => 'Arizona');
```

i want filter these two array and i want final result as array like this 
first array like this

```
$zones_array3 = array();
      $zones_array3[] = array('id' => 'Alabama', 'text' => 'Alabama');
      $zones_array3[] = array('id' => 'Arkansas', 'text' => 'Arkansas');
```

please help me

Comment: Try iteration across array1, using a conditional based on in_array. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: if you can explain how do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use php 'in_array' to check weather an element exists inside other array or not. In you case the array is multidimensional so stored all the id's inside a newly created array and then compared the given array with that.

```
$check_array = array();
foreach ($zones_array1 as $arr1){
      $check_array[] = $arr1['id'];
}

$zones_array3 = array();

foreach ($zones_array2 as $arr2){
 if (!in_array($arr2['id'], $check_array))
  {
         $zones_array3[] = $arr2;
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($zones_array3);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional explanation regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would make it more helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

```
function udiffCompare($a, $b)
{
    return $a['id'] == $b['id'] ? 0 : -1;
}

$arrdiff = array_udiff($zones_array1, $zones_array2, 'udiffCompare');

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrdiff);
```

`array_udiff()` compares each element of the first array-argument against all the elements of the second array-argument using the provided callback function.  If the callback returns zero for any of the comparisons then the element of the array in the first argument will not be present in the returned array of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You will try it :

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key){
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val){
        if(!in_array($val[$key],$key_array)){
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}

$zones_array1 = array_merge($zones_array2, $zones_array3);
$zones_array1 = unique_multidim_array($zones_array1, 'id');
print_r($zones_array1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
    array_push($zones_array1,$zones_array2);
print_r(array_unique($zones_array1));
```

I am not sure.

Comment: Well, then, Ensure!! regardless of the generated warnings, It will not produce what the OP wants!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010717/php-compare-and-filter-two-arrays-with-different-dimensions check this link

Comment: Seriously?!! I think you neither have read that very question nor this one!! However, the concept you've failed to accomplish is good enough! Firstly, the `array_push()` function appends the `$zones_array2` argument _to the end of_ the first argument, so that after the execution of the function, the fist first parameter will have _the whole of_ the `$array_zone2` as the last element. Despite that, the [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function compares the array elements as if they are strings, not like a multidimensional array!!